# Inject instances that implement generic inteface w/o specifying the generic type

Tags: c#, autofac

I want to inject collection of instances that implement a generic interface without specifying the type. What I want:

```
public MyConstructor(IEnumerable<MyGenericInterface<>> implementations) 
{
      //Autofac injects implementations...
}
```

What kind of works is digging into container registrations using reflection like this:

```
var genericRegistrations= container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.Where(r => r.Activator.LimitType.GetInterfaces().Any(x=>x.IsGenericType&&x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(MyGenericInterface<>))).Select(r => r.Activator.LimitType);
var typesThatImplementMyGenericInterface= container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.Where(r => genericRegistrations.Any(x=>x.IsAssignableFrom(r.Activator.LimitType))).Select(r => r.Activator.LimitType);

var implementations= typesThatImplementMyGenericInterface.Select(t => container.Resolve(t));
```

The problems I have with this is that I had to register the implementations with `.AsSelf()` instead of `.AsImplementedIntefaces()` like I would actually like to register them. Another problem is that this requires me to refer to the container in business logic code or write some other wrapper/provider that would dig into the container and it just ruins the Autofac magic.

Comment: `IEnumerable<MyGenericInterface<>> implementations` wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @YacoubMassad of course... I just meant to demonstrate the desired use.

Comment: It might help to show some "real code" that isn't working. If you try to resolve `IEnumerable<MyGenericInterface<ClosedType>>` it should work if such a thing is registered. Querying the list of registrations like you have in the example isn't recommended because it won't give you a complete list - registration sources and dynamic registrations won't be found. What's the use case?

Comment: What you want is only possible if you let the generic interface derive from a non-generic interface and inject an enumerable of that non-generic interface into consumers.